# Proof of multiplier formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, geometric-series

I don't understand two parts in the formula. In the first place how can we remove the sommation? Finally, in the last part how are the beta zero and the phi before the beta zero handled? Thank you in advance

$$\beta_0+\sum_{j=1}^\infty\phi^{j-1}(\phi\beta_0+\beta_1)=\beta_0+\frac{\phi\beta_0+\beta_1}{1-\phi}=\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1}{1-\phi}.$$

Comment: 1) geometric series 2) simple algebra

Comment: Use $\sum_i \alpha a_i=\alpha\sum_i a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}q^i=q/(1-q)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since\begin{align}\sum_{j=1}^N\phi^{j-1}(\phi\beta_0+\beta_1)&=\beta_0\sum_{j=1}^N\phi^j+\beta_1\sum_{j=1}^N\phi^{j-1}\\&=\beta_0\frac{\phi-\phi^{N+1}}{1-\phi}+\beta_1\frac{1-\phi^N}{1-\phi},\end{align}we have\begin{align}\sum_{j=1}^\infty\phi^{j-1}(\phi\beta_0+\beta_1)&=\beta_0\frac\phi{1-\phi}+\frac{\beta_1}{1-\phi}\\&=\frac{\beta_0\phi+\beta_1}{1-\phi}.\end{align}It should be clear that$$\beta_0+\frac{\beta_0\phi+\beta_1}{1-\phi}=\frac{\beta_0+\beta_1}{1-\phi}.$$

Comment: You needn't split the series into two, as the parenthesised expression is constant w.r.t. $j$, hence $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty\phi^{j-1}(\phi\beta_0+\beta_1) = (\phi\beta_0+\beta_1)\cdot\sum_{j=1}^\infty\phi^{j-1}$$

Comment: Right you are! You could have posted that.

Comment: M. Winter gave this hint in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448676/proof-of-multiplier-formula#comment5058822_2448676), I just expanded it. So I won't post it as my own answer.